# Issue Running "npm run prisma migrate dev" - Need Assistance

Tags: prisma

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/E56PB.jpg)

I am encountering an issue when attempting to run "npm run prisma migrate dev" in my project. I've provided a screenshot of the error here. While I am aware that using "prisma db push" is a workaround, I am keen on addressing the root cause of the problem. The database I am working with is PostgreSQL on ElephantSQL. Any guidance on resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.